# Laravel : How to copy a mysql table structure with DB?

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel,
I want to copy a table structure with `DB`,I do it like this:

```
DB::raw('CREATE TABLE articles_tmp LIKE articles');
```

But it doesn't work.
what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

`DB::unprepared('CREATE TABLE articles_tmp LIKE articles');`